# Frustrating error with sqlite cross table update

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

For some reason the following query returns the following error message in sqlite. I normally use cross table joins but as this is not possible for updates in sqlite it's a sub-query instead. This could be a case of tired eyes but I can't seem to see the issue. Any help is appreciated.

> near "." : Syntax Error

```
  UPDATE
    tbl1
    set tbl1.[some_field1] = (SELECT tbl2.[some_fieldA]||substr(tbl2.[some_fieldB],1,2)     
                              FROM tbl2
                               WHERE tbl2.[some_fieldC] = tbl1.[some_field2])
  WHERE
    tbl1.[file_name] = "some_arbitrary_file.txt"
    AND tbl1.[some_field1] IS NULL 
    OR tbl1.[some_field1] = "";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UPDATE` command handles only one table, so it is never necessary to specify the table for the columns to be updated.
Drop the `tbl1.` in the `SET`:

```
... SET [some_field1] = ...
```

Comment: ah my god, I knew it had to be something simple like this. Thanks a million. It seems amazing that the interpreter would not ok it since the table name is correct. Then again I'm sure they have their reasons. All the best.